# R - Order and Plot with long format data

Tags: r, ggplot2, dataframe

I am having trouble ordering and plotting line graphs with my following dataframe:
[image]

I could pass the whole database, but it has 1152. The point is that it is in long format and with "Id" an identification variable which repeats itself for each type (I suspect this is causing confusion).

I am trying to make a line ggplot but it gives me:

```
ggplot(data=plotDFdataLong,
                aes(x=Id, y=Stat, colour=Types, group=Types)) +
            geom_line()
```

[image]

Also, when I try to order:

```
plotDFdataLong <- plotDFdataLong[order(plotDFdataLong$Id,
                                       plotDFdataLong$Types),]
```

I get:

```
Error in xj[i, , drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
```

Any hints?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you make your example reproducible, or perhaps provide dummy data such as, `df <- data.frame(id = rep(1:10, 10),
                 type = rep(paste0("T", 1:10), each = 10),
                 stat = rnorm(100))`

Comment: check if `Types` is a factor

Comment: Yes, `Types`is a factor.

Comment: Ok, problem was with datatypes; should I answer my own question?

Comment: @user191919 Yes, do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was with datatypes. Originally they were:

```
       Id     Types      Stat 
"numeric"  "factor"  "matrix"
```

The dummy dataframe below was working fine:

```
data.frame(id = rep(1:10, 10), type = rep(paste0("T", 1:10), each = 10), stat = rnorm(100))
```

which had the following class:

```
sapply(df,class)
       id      type      stat 
"integer"  "factor" "numeric"
```

So it is just a question of transforming the data into the class above.